# How do we create Dynamic Tables in Excel based on the input provided in a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was looking if there was any way to possibly do this in Excel, maybe by using VBA or any other concepts.

The below image shows the input-form, where the user gives the required details about the Company going from 1.1 to 1.5.

[Input Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmXOq.jpg)

Now, I want to generate tables based on the value entered in 1.4 of the input form dynamically. The table structure is shown below.

[Generated Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXq8n.jpg)

How can I achieve this task? Any help would be great. I'm open to learn about any concepts that can make this task easier.

Thank you!

Comment: Please share your attempts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.